# converting type result of for-comprehension in scala

Tags: scala, types, for-comprehension

```
case class Array_8to24[T](val arr:Array[T]) {
  def tail():Array[T] = {
    for(i <- 1 until arr.length toArray) yield arr(i)
  }
}
```

Compiler says that tail() returns ArraySeq[T], I expected Array[T]

BTW swaps() works as expected

```
def swaps(arr:Array[Int]):Array[Int] = {
    for(i <- 0 until arr.length toArray) yield {      
      if((i+1)%2 != 0 && i+1<arr.length){
        arr(i + 1)
      }else {
        arr(if(i==arr.length-1 && arr.length%2!=0) i else i - 1)
      }
    }
  }
```

How to return Array[T] from tail()?

Comment: how about `arr.tail`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem is that it does not know how to create an array of unknown type `T`. Arrays are a special kind of containers because they are backed by native java arrays, and for that reason one needs to have the element type when the array is instantiated. Adding manifest to the declaration should fix it:

```
case class Array_8to24[T : Manifest](val arr:Array[T]) {
  def tail(): Array[T] = 
    for(i <- 1 until arr.length toArray) yield arr(i)
}
```

You do know you could just do `arr.tail` or `arr.drop(1)`, right?
And `swaps` could be `arr.grouped(2).flatMap { case Array(a,b) => Array(b,a) case x => x }.toArray`

Comment: Manifest is a part of scala reflection library, it carries some information about the type, such as the actual runtime class it is referring to. Adding it to the class declaration like this creates an implicit parameter that will be available at run time, and can be used to instantiate the array of the correct type. Basically, when you create a concrete instance of your class like `Array_8to24(Array(1,2,3)`, the compiler will generate a `Manifest` instance for `Int` and pass it down to the class, so that the type information is preserved and can be used whenever `tail` is called.